# Iterating without for loop in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, iterator, vectorization

I need to do logical iteration over numpy array, which's values depend on elements of other array. I've written code below for clarifying my problem. Any suggestions to solve this problem without for loop?

```
Code
a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a'])
b = np.array([150, 154, 147, 126, 148, 125])
c = np.zeros_like(b)
c[0] = 150
for i in range(1, c.size):
    if a[i] == "b":
        c[i] = c[i-1]
    else:
        c[i] = b[i]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach using a combination of [`np.maximum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) and [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to create stepped indices that are to be *stopped* at certain intervals and then simply indexing into `b` would give us the desired output.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
mask = a!="b"
idx = np.maximum.accumulate(np.where(mask,np.arange(mask.size),0))
out = b[idx]
```

Sample step-by-step run -

```
In [656]: # Inputs 
     ...: a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a'])
     ...: b = np.array([150, 154, 147, 126, 148, 125])
     ...: 

In [657]: mask = a!="b"

In [658]: mask
Out[658]: array([ True, False,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

# Crux of the implmentation happens here :
In [696]: np.where(mask,np.arange(mask.size),0)
Out[696]: array([0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 5])

In [697]: np.maximum.accumulate(np.where(mask,np.arange(mask.size),0))
Out[697]: array([0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 5])# Stepped indices "intervaled" at masked places

In [698]: idx = np.maximum.accumulate(np.where(mask,np.arange(mask.size),0))

In [699]: b[idx]
Out[699]: array([150, 150, 147, 126, 126, 125])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a more vectorized approach Like so:

```
np.where(a == "b", np.roll(c, 1), b)
```

`np.where` will take the elements from `np.roll(c, 1)` if the condition is `True` or it will take from `b` if the condition is `False`. `np.roll(c, 1)` will "roll" forward all the elements of `c` by 1 so that each element refers to `c[i-1]`.

These type of operations are what make numpy so invaluable. Looping should be avoided if possible.

Comment: That's simple and concise solution. But, why it returns [150   0 147 126   0 125]? It doesn't take values from 'b' array where a[i] = "b".

Comment: I misread the question, this only works if you already have all the elements of `c` but you are populating it through the loop so it makes it a little bit more complicated than this

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to wrap around the margin there is a very simply solution:

```
a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a'])
b = np.array([150, 154, 147, 126, 148, 125])
c = b.copy()  #removes necessity of else case
c[a[:-1]=='b'] = c[a[1:]=='b']
```

or equally:

```
a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a'])
b = np.array([150, 154, 147, 126, 148, 125])
c = b.copy()  #removes necessity of else case
mask = a == 'b'
c[mask[:-1]] = c[mask[1:]]
```

If you want to wrap around the margin (`a[0]=='b'`) then it gets a little more complicated, you either need to use `roll` or catch this case first with and `if`.